# Make the Enter key act like the submit button

Tags: c#

How can I make it where some one presses the enter key on my form it will submit this code ?

Ive tried the KeyPress events etc... but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
 private void
 xTripSubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    //  Calculates the numbers from the input and output boxes/labels
    Miles = double.Parse(this.xTripDestinationTextBox.Text);
    Mpg = double.Parse(this.xTripMpgTextBox.Text);
    Price = double.Parse(this.xTripPricepgTextBox.Text);
    Output = Miles / Mpg;
    Coutput = Output * Price;

    //displays a message and the result for the numbers the user inputs
    this.xTripOutputLabel.Text = "Total gallons you would use: " +
        Output.ToString("0") +
        Environment.NewLine + "Total amount it will cost you: " +
         Coutput.ToString("C"); 

    }
```

Comment: `ligtning bolt events` - Classic :)

Comment: You're asking for a asp.net or winforms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is WinForms, set the form's [`AcceptButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton.aspx) property to be the button you want to have a click simulated on, when they press <kbd>enter</kbd>. Then, in that button's event handler, call `Close()` or better still, set the `DialogResult` property

Answer (score 6):

You can set the **AcceptButton** property of the form to your button :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton.aspx

> "Gets or sets the button on the form that is clicked when the user presses the ENTER key."

Answer (score 0):

Well if you use winforms what I think you do there is a keypress event:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Enter is a key press.  You need to make a key press event handler.